# What is wrong with this syntax of my ejs code?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to use `if/else` in ejs but whenever I add the `else` part an error shows up.

```
<% if (user) {%>


<%=user.twitter.username%>

<%}%>

<%=else{%>

    Hi hi 
<%}%>
```

The error says: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token else in C:\Users\Adetona\Dropbox\meme.africa\views\pages\index.ejs while compiling ejs`

Whenever I removed the `else` part everything works well.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: it's the `<%=else{`. you must not use the `=` sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<% %>` means that you are making an expression or declaring a variable etc...

`<%- %>` the text will be printed but not escaped you could still do calculation inside like `(a > b) ? a : b;`

`<%= %>` will escape **html** lets say you are getting a user input and print it on the screen then you want that to be escaped.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to pair the `else` with the end of the previous conditional block, so:

```
<% if (user) { %>
  ...
<% } else { %>
  ...
<% } %>
```

Comment: Working perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The ejs view engine needs to understand that it's compiling an if-else block so try writing it as shown below

Place the curly braces as shown below and tag it appropriately.

```
if { 
// if block code statements 

} else {
//else block code statements
}
```

so it becomes

```
<% if { %>
// if block code statements 

<% } else { %>
//else block code statements
<% } %>
```